# will sencha-charts work without sencha-touch?

Tags: html, sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-charts

I have downloaded sancha touch-charts.If i want to host in my local host,I have to install sencha touch? will sencha-charts work without sencha-touch? how can I configure both in webserver?because sencha-charts is add-on of sencha-touch?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Touch Charts is an addon for Sencha Touch and requires you load sencha-touch.js before loading touch-charts.js. When you download the Touch Charts beta, Sencha Touch is included in the download and the examples provide everything you need to get started.